# MissingMethodException Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, servicestack, servicestack-text, missingmethodexception

Because of this blog-post:

https://www.radenkozec.com/8-ways-improve-asp-net-web-api-performance/

I´ve tried to replace JSON.net with ServiceStack.Text as JSON-Serializer in my WebApi.
With this tutorial:

https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/replace-json-net-with-servicestack-text-in-asp-net-web-api/

Localhost and in debug-mode all went well, until I deployed it to our server, it says:

> MissingMethodException
>
> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler> System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_MessageHandlers()".]

It happens at Application_Start().

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

}
```

Thats my replacement:

```
public class ServiceStackTextFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public ServiceStackTextFormatter()
    {
        JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: true, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        return true;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream(type, readStream));
        return task;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream(value, type, writeStream));
        return task;
    }
}
```

And my Register method:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // see this: https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/replace-json-net-with-servicestack-text-in-asp-net-web-api/
        // and this: https://www.radenkozec.com/8-ways-improve-asp-net-web-api-performance/
        // ServiceStackText is much faster than JSON.NET
        config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new ServiceStackTextFormatter());

        // add Handler to send data chunked
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new Handler());

        // Web API configuration and services
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.EnableCors();      // needed to disable this, otherwise we do not get a access-origin-header in the client
        
        config.Formatters[0].SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        config.Formatters[0].SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        config.Formatters[0].SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        (config.Formatters[0] as ServiceStackTextFormatter).SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I made some progress. The problem was not caused by the ServiceStack-JSON-Serializer, it's caused by my Handler which is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace akiliBase.Rest.RestAPI.Models
{
    public class Handler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            response.Result.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true; // Here!

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

So I deleted this line and will ask another question about this.

Now I get the following error:

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found:
> "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1<System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue>
> System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter.get_SupportedMediaTypes()".]

which is caused by the following lines:

```
config.Formatters[0].SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
config.Formatters[0].SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
config.Formatters[0].SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

So it seams in `System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter` the getter for SupportedMediaTypes is missing. I also think the whole problem is caused in Web.config where some wrong assemblies are referenced or something. So here is my web.config-runtime-tag:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.0.0" newVersion="15.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ZedGraph" publicKeyToken="02a83cbd123fcd60" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.7.430" newVersion="5.1.7.430" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```